# ListView.builder is not scrollable when data is loaded

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm working on a flutter blog project and when the app is started it's scrollable but after the data is loaded it is not scrollable. Here's the code that I'm using,

```
Widget BlogsList() {
  if (blogStream != null){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: blogStream!,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              // if (snapshot.data==null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return BlogsTile(
                authorName: snapshot.data.docs[index]['authorName'],
                title: snapshot.data.docs[index]["title"],
                description: snapshot.data.docs[index]["desc"],
                imgUrl: snapshot.data.docs[index]["imgUrl"],              
              );
             },
           );
          },
         ),
       ],
      )
    );
  }
  else {
    return Container(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `SingleChildScrollView`,

```
...
 if (blogStream != null){
       return Column(
         children: [
           ...
```